# Xcode SVN commit error

Tags: xcode, svn, repository, commit, google-code

this is driving me nuts. My SVN repo is working fine, I was able to checkout everything and view revisions in Xcode's organiser.

It is only when I go to commit the changes that i hit this ridiculous problem:

[image]

After a lot of research I found the only people getting this problem were those who didn't realise that there is a separate password for google code than your google account password. My password is correct.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks a lot

Comment: Does it work from the terminal? cd to the directory of the project and try to commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this is due to some bug in Xcode I think. What you have to do to get around it is:

- Firstly set up your repository in Organiser
- Open the project in Xcode and make a change
- Try to commit this change in Xcode. You will get the error above
- Now commit the change to your repository using the `svn` command in the terminal
- Now make another change and commit it using Xcode. It will work